# soda (socrata) NYPD Motor Vehicle Collisions API Cross-origin resource sharing

Tags: socrata, soda

I'm trying to create a mashup using the NYPD Motor Vehicle Collisions API and Google Maps JavaScript API. I'd like to know if I can load data directly from the NYC API to the Maps API using Cross-origin resource sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can! Here are some more details: https://dev.socrata.com/docs/cors-and-jsonp.html